# Biblatex: all entries indented in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber

The other day I was working on my paper, when all entries in the bibliography were suddenly indented -- as if they belong to one entry. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Interestingly, when I copied my bibsettings and tried to make a MWE, the error did not reproduce when I cited a few random entries:

[image]

Since they both use the same .bib file, this seemed to suggest that the error is either caused a particular entry not cited in my (failed) MWE, or by some other error in the main document of my paper. Anyhow, maybe some of you recognises this issue and knows a solution -- would be great!

Thanks,
M

Comment: Mhh, I think I have seen this before when there was an error in one of the bib items, but this is really just a guess. Would it be possible to find the offending entry? It could also be that it is not a certain entry, but something before the bibliography or a `\defbibenvironment` or something. Do you get any errors or warnings (check the `.log` file)?

Comment: Thanks! Strangely, no errors.  Also, I don't use the \defbibenvironment but the settings on their own don't reproduce the error so I think its not that... 

I guess I should inspect all entries but I don't really know what to look for -- any suggestions?

Comment: Update: I cited all entries in my "MWE" but still the error did not reproduce. I guess It's something in the document after all? 

Tonight I will try to copy all the content into a new file and see what happens. If, in the meantime anyone has a suggestion, i'd be happy to hear!

Comment: Mhhh, it could be any number of reasons. Maybe you have a "leaking" environment before the bibliography. Using the binary search method it should hopefully not take too long to create an MWE.

Comment: Any updates here? Without further hints this is just guesswork.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Actually, I stumbled into a more serious error (a fatal error, "you can't use end in internal vertical mode") and started checking, commenting, and modifying all environments. This I did in great panic, since the deadline was approaching. When the fatal error was finally resolved, the bibliography was also fixed. Which means that it was a leaking environment, indeed, but I don't know exactly which one, because I didn't work very systematically, I'm afraid. 

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: OK, I will vote to close your question then as "unclear what you are asking", since you resolved the problem yourself and it is not at all clear from your question what the problem was, as such the question is quite unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: I voted to close this question as "unclear what you are asking", since the issue has been resolved by the OP, is not clear from the question alone and the problem was in fact just a side-effect of another problem.